# Finding kinetic energies of two electrons with velocities $0.90c$ and $0.99c$ respectively

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, energy, kinematics

Suppose, we have an inertial frame of reference $S$, which is at rest. Two electrons are moving at velocities $0.90c$ and $0.99c$ with respect to S. Now, what will be the ratio of their kinetic energies?

Given,

mass of the electrons at rest, $m_o=9.1\times10^{-31}kg$

changed mass of 1st electron when in motion, $m_1=2.087 \times10^{-30} kg$

changed mass of 2nd electron when in motion, $m_2=6.45\times10^{-30} kg$

velocity of 1st electron, $v_1=0.90c$

velocity of 2nd electron, $v_2=0.99c$

Now, ratio of two kinetic energies $E_{k_2}$ & $E_{k_1}$ is

$$\frac{E_{k_1}}{E_{k_2}}=\frac{0.5\times 2.087 \times10^{-30}\times{(0.9c)}^2}{0.5\times6.45\times10^{-30}\times(0.99c)^2}$$

$$\implies \frac{E_{k_1}}{E_{k_2}}= 2.674\times10^{-1}$$

$$\implies \frac{E_{k_2}}{E_{k_1}}= 3.7397$$

Now, this is pretty straightforward. We found the ratio of the two kinetic energies, but my book did this in a very weird way. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rovqn.jpg) is what my book did.

Is my answer or process wrong or is the book's process wrong?

Comment: What you call weird is actually special relativity.

Comment: An electron has only 1 value for its mass. You (or your tutor) are using the deprecated, obsolete concept of 'relativistic mass'. Unfortunately this is also suggested by the suffix in the answer of @Nyra. The error is also encouraged in the comment of Murray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the Newtonian kinetic energy equation; it is the low-speed approximation, derived from the Maclaurin series, of the relativistic kinetic energy equation. it breaks down at speeds>~0.2c (from memory)

for high speeds you need $E_k=(\gamma-1)m_0c^2$ where $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{v}{c})^2}}$

so $\frac{E_{k1}}{E_{k2}}=\frac{\gamma_1-1}{\gamma_2-1}$

hopefully that helps

Comment: +1 It's also worth noting, as per the OP's linked solution, that if you insist on phrasing the answer in terms of the relativistic mass $m=\gamma m_0$, then you can express $E_k = (\gamma-1)m_0c^2 = (m-m_0)c^2$.

Comment: Please edit in $m_o$ instead of $m$